# Find the centroid in the first quadrant which is between $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=9$

Tags: calculus, integration, circles, centroid

Let $R$ be the region in the first quadrant which is between $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=9$. Find the centroid of $R$.

Comment: Do you have the Centroid Formulas at hand? Part 1 is to calculate the Area $A$ of the Region in Question. Normally that is done through an integral, but here that can be done without, because $A$ is a region between concentric circles. $x^2+y^2=9$ is the upper curve and $x^2+y^2=4$ is the lower. For your learning experience, show us some steps here. PS, there is symmetry for the centroid coordinates

Comment: Have you learned how to find a centroid using polar coordinates?

Comment: I agree that polar is actually the way to go...

Comment: Integrate[kr^2,{theta,0,pi/2},{r,2,3}] = (19pi/6)*k   ,this is what i get for mass. But i have no idea really if i set the integral up right or  if I'm on the right track. Sorry if my integral is not written nicely. I wrote it the way i would write it in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can describe the region in polar coordinates with $r \in [2,3]$ and $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

The centroid is the center of mass of our object assuming constant $\delta=c$ density.

$$\frac{M}{A}=c$$

$$M=cA$$

$$\bar x=\frac{1}{M} \iint_{D} \delta xdA$$

$$\bar x=\frac{1}{cA}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{2}^{3} c r\cos(\theta) rdr d\theta$$

$$=\frac{4}{5\pi} \int_{2}^{3} r^2 dr  \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} cos(\theta) d\theta$$

$$=\frac{4}{5\pi} \frac{19}{3} =\frac{76}{5\pi}$$

$$\bar y=\frac{1}{M} \iint_{D} \delta ydA$$

$$\bar y=\frac{1}{cA}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{2}^{3} c r\sin(\theta) rdrd\theta$$

The mass is what you get when you add up all the densities times a small change in area,

$$M=\iint_{D} \delta dA$$

In this case we have $\delta=k$ where $k$ is a constant or $c$ if you wish, then we have:

$$M=\iint_{D} k dA=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{2}^{3} k rdrd\theta=\frac{5\pi}{4}k$$

In fact because we have $\frac{M}{A}=k$ then we have, $M=kA=k\frac{1}{4}(\pi(3^2)-\pi(2^2))$. Also note that,

$$\iint_{D} dA=\text{Area}(D)$$

(We're adding small areas of D to make the whole area of D).

So multiplying by $k$ gives,

$$\iint_{D} k dA=k\text{Area}(D)$$

Comment: @CalcGuy Note that because of the symmetry you will find that $\bar{x}=\bar{y}$ for this particular problem.

Comment: Symmetry of $x$ and $y$ in the equations $x^2+y^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=9$ and the density function $=c$. Just to make sure @JohnWaylandBales right?

Comment: Ok. But in my comment above, did i set up my Mass integral correct?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Correct. CalcGuy I have never used Mathematica so I cannot comment on your Mass integral. When I worked the problem I got $\bar{x}=\bar{y}=\dfrac{76}{15\pi}$. I think that is correct but did not double check.

Comment: You have an extra $r$ in your setup @CalcGuy. Care to explain why you put it there, or if that was just a typo.

Comment: I was just following an example in my calculus textbook.

Comment: If added some notes @CalcGuy please check them out.

Comment: Here is a link to a Desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ycgbeacogs

Comment: For Mx I get 5/2, which does not give me  y¯ = 76/15pi. So I am not sure where I went wrong